# Replace text occurrences with data returned by Promises

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, promise, bluebird

I've got a blog-post like this:

```
var post ="## Cool Post [embed]https://soundcloud.com/wonnemusik/teaser-schotone-dear-thomson-button-remix[/embed]"
+ "Here comes another one  [embed]https://soundcloud.com/straightech-bonn-podcast/straightech-and-friends-7-oscar-ozz[/embed]";
```

Now for every occurrence of `[embed]soundcloud-url[/embed]` I need to call their API endpoint `http://api.soundcloud.com/resolve.json?url=soundcloud-url&client_id=my-id`, parse the returned JSON and replace the `[embed]` with my own markup.

**How can I use this using Promises?**

```
var post ="## Cool Post [embed]https://soundcloud.com/wonnemusik/teaser-schotone-dear-thomson-button-remix[/embed]"
+ "Here comes another one  [embed]https://soundcloud.com/straightech-bonn-podcast/straightech-and-friends-7-oscar-ozz[/embed]"
var re = /\[embed\](.*)\[\/embed\]/gm;
var m;

do {
    m = re.exec(post);
    if (m) {
      var apiCallUrl = "http://api.soundcloud.com/resolve.json?url=" + m[1] '&client_id=...'
      request(apiCallUrl).then(function(body) {
        var trackinfo = JSON.parse(body[0].body)
        return trackinfo.title
     }
    }
} while (m);

// have all promises fulfilled and old embed in post-var replaced
```

Comment: I'm not so sure what you're asking, I hope my guess is right; 
Declare a var, probably preferable an array. Add your return value to that array at each do{}. At the end use your array to replace the old var.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used `bluebird` specifically, but there's usually [an `all` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) that wraps an array of promises (or takes promises as arguments). A glance at the API documentation for bluebird shows they do have an [`all`](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#all---promise) method that you can use. You'll want to create an array of promises inside your do/while loop, then call `all` at the end:

```
var resultPromises = [];
var m;
do {
    m = re.exec(post);
    if (m) {
        var apiCallUrl = "http://api.soundcloud.com/resolve.json?url=" + m[1] '&client_id=...'
        resultPromises.push(request(apiCallUrl));
    }
} while (m);

// have all promises fulfilled and old embed in post-var replaced
Promise.all(resultPromises).then(function (results) {
    // do stuff.
});
```

Now, if you want to replace the original text with the results of the promise, you'll need to store the matches in an array as well. The `results` argument to the `then` will be an array of the responses, in the order in which they were originally added to the array. So, you can do something like:

```
var resultPromises = [];
var matches = [];
var m;
do {
    m = re.exec(post);
    if (m) {
        var apiCallUrl = "http://api.soundcloud.com/resolve.json?url=" + m[1] '&client_id=...'
        resultPromises.push(request(apiCallUrl));
        matches.push(m);
    }
} while (m);

var i = 0;
// have all promises fulfilled and old embed in post-var replaced
Promise.all(resultPromises).then(function (results) {
    // haven't tested this. Will leave as practice for the OP :)
    post = post.replace(matches[i], results[i].body[0].body.title);
    i += 1;
});
```

Comment: Both answers are excellent. I went with your approach so this one is the answer for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [this `replace` function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27442256/1048572) that deals with asynchronous callbacks:

```
var post = "## Cool Post [embed]https://soundcloud.com/wonnemusik/teaser-schotone-dear-thomson-button-remix[/embed]"
         + "Here comes another one  [embed]https://soundcloud.com/straightech-bonn-podcast/straightech-and-friends-7-oscar-ozz[/embed]"
var re = /\[embed\](.*)\[\/embed\]/gm;

return replaceAsync(post, re, function(m, url) {
     var apiCallUrl = "http://api.soundcloud.com/resolve.json?url=" + url + '&client_id=…'
     return request(apiCallUrl).then(function(res) {
         return JSON.parse(res[0].body).title;
     });
});
```